# JPA Hibernate Converter is not called with Spring Data QBE

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot Application and I've made a converter (for convert string to date and date to string). With standards CRUD methods like "findByName()" (which JPARepository make easiest to create), the converter is called and work very well.

Now, I've tried to run a QBE. When I run my QBE, my converter is not called.

This is my entity where my converter is called:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOOTABLE")
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    @Convert(converter = DateStringConverter.class)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

}
```

My converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DateStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, String> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(String databaseDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.FRENCH);
        try {
            return formatter.parse(databaseDate);
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date arg0) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        return formatter.format(arg0);
    }
}
```

My QBE:

```
 public SearchResultatModel<MyModel> read(CriteriaModel criteria) {
    SearchResultatModel<MyModel> result = new SearchResultatModel<>();
    List<MyModel> results = new ArrayList<>();

    MyModel myExemple = prepareExemple(criteria);

    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIncludeNullValues().withIgnorePaths("id", "imsi", "mnc");
    Example<MyModel> example = Example.of(myExemple, matcher);
    results.addAll(DBRepo.findAll(example));

    result.setResults(results);
    return result;
}

 public MyModel prepareExemple(CriteriaModel criteria) {
    MyModel exemple = new MyModel();

    if(StringUtils.isNoneBlank(criteria.getId())) {
        exemple.setId(criteria.getId());
    }
    if(criteria.getDate() != null) {
        exemple.setDate(criteria.getDate());
    }
    if(StringUtils.isNoneBlank(criteria.getName())) {
        exemple.setName(criteria.getName());
    }

    return exemple;
 }
```

DBRepo is an autowired portout, this is my JpaRepository.
I've run my application in debug mode and I've put a breakpoint in my converter.
I never pass by this breakpoint.

Converter can works with QBE? I've miss something?